# Usercontrol with Property List<Class> where class is abstract

Tags: c#, .net

I wrote a UserControl which is derived from a standard Control.

This UserControl has a Property which is a list of a abstract class.
But i get an Error of the PropertyGrid which say that it could not create a new instance of the abstract class because it's abstract.

What can i do to handle this?

Comment: Code is not really needed for this. The information that is provided clearly states what the problem is.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the bad explanation, we wonna have a list to choose which implementation of base class to add..

Answer (score 2):

Abstract classes cannot be created, they must be implemented.

> An abstract class is a class that cannot be instantiated, but must be inherited from

This is why you see an error from the PropertyGrid.

You will need to create a base class that implements all or some of your abstract class or 
you might be able to use an interface.

[Abstact VS Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scsyfw1d%28VS.71%29.aspx).